# When do you talk to a friend sometimes, you will have to talk patiently. - if I put "sometimes" at the beginning, will the meaning change?

Tags: meaning

Example 1

> Sometimes, when you talk to a friend, you will have to talk patiently.

Example 2

> When you talk to a friend sometimes, you will have to talk patiently.

What are the differences in meaning?

Does in example one the "sometimes" modify the main clause "you will have to talk patiently"?

Does in example two the "sometimes" modify the subordinate clause "when you to a friend" meaning this action only happens sometimes?

Comment: I've removed the word "do" from your second example,  The rest of the question suggests you are only asking about the position of sometimes, so the grammar error introduced by inserting "do" is a typo not part of the question.  I've removed "do" so answers won't be distracted by that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. is not the idiomatic location of the adverb "sometimes".  But you could form the sentence:

> 2b. When you talk to a friend, sometimes you have to talk patiently.

Note the position of the comma.

While you could split hairs about the difference between 1. and 2b. There really is very little difference in how these would be understood. The formal modification may be different, but the underlying sense is the same.